# Simulating SELECT YEAR(post_date) SQL query using only WP Query

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, function, date

I'm not entirely sure this is possible but I'm completely out of ideas. The task I'm working on requires that I specifically use WP_Query due to constraints of other efficiency plugins my organization uses.

Pure and simple, I need a way to simulate the following query using WP_Query:

`"SELECT YEAR(post_date) FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY YEAR(post_date) DESC"`

Before you answer, note again, using the $wpdb global is off the table, and I've attempted to employ the parse_query method from WP_Query but it doesn't seem to respond to the above query in any meaningful way.

Thank you to anyone who takes the time to think this over!

Comment: `$query = "SELECT YEAR(post_date) FROM $wpdb->posts  WHERE post_status = 'publish'  GROUP BY 1 DESC";`  (modified from one of the responses here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-raw-query-instead-of-meta_query/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably try this:

```
<?php
//Alter the group by clause
function query_group_by_year_post_date_filter($groupby){
   return 'YEAR(wp_posts.post_date) DESC '; //try only post_date if this doesn't work
}
//Alter the select query
function query_select_fields($fields) {
  return 'YEAR(wp_posts.post_date)'; //try only post_date if this doesn't work
}

add_filter('posts_fields','query_select_fields');
add_filter('posts_groupby', 'query_group_by_year_post_date_filter'); 
$allPosts = get_posts(array( //we have to use get_posts instead of WP_Query cause get_posts supports supress_filters
    'post_type' => 'post', //specify post_type here or leave it in your case.
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'suppress_filters' => true //this seems to be preset in only get_posts and not WP_Query
)); 
remove_filter('posts_groupby', 'query_group_by_filter');
remove_filter('posts_fields','query_select_fields');
?>
```

I've tried not to use $wpdb in 2 functions at the top as per your requirements.

let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: Bingo! Although it seems you can use the WP_Query object just fine, and just not suppress filters. Thanks Vinay!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. And thank you for confirming that we don't require supress filter as well as it works with wp_query.